# Higher Order Haskell Functions Applied to Trees

Tags: haskell, tree, higher-order-functions

I have the data type

```
data Tree a = Null | Node a {lTree, rTree :: Tree a}
```

I want to rewrite the following higher order functions so that they can apply to trees.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b 

fold :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> Tree b -> a

foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> Tree b -> a 

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b 

filter :: (a -> Bool) -> Tree a -> Tree a 

zip :: Tree a -> Tree b -> Tree (a,b)
```

I want to know how to write the functions explicitly, for example I know that the map function can be written:

```
treeMap :: (a ->b) -> Tree a -> Tree b 
treeMap f tree = case tree of 
    Null -> Null 
    Node a Null Null -> Node (f a) Null Null 
    Node a l r -> Node (f a) (treeMap f l) (treeMap f r)
```

Comment: With the pragmas `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable #-}` you can just add `... deriving (Functor, Foldable)` to the data declaration and GHC will do the first four for you.

Comment: How would `filter` for trees work?

Comment: I want to know how to write the functions explicitly, for example I know that the map function can be written: 

treeMap :: (a ->b) -> Tree a -> Tree b 

treeMap f tree = case tree of 

 Null -> Null 

 Node a Null Null -> Node (f a) Null Null 

 Node a l r -> Node (f a) (treeMap f l) (treeMap f r)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson if the top node's value is eliminated, the two updated branches can be joined by pulling up the rightmost element from the left, or leftmost from the right updated branch.

Comment: @WillNess, as we know nothing about what the tree *means*, we have no particular reason to believe that the operation you suggest makes any sense.

Comment: @dfeuer my suggestion follows the "lisp congruency", same as chi's answer. both make sense or don't in the same way, I think. so yes, of course it's somewhat arbitrary. (that's why I said "can", and not e.g. "must"; indeed  I should've perhaps said "may" or even "might" :) ).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a step-by-step approach. We will focus on `treeFoldr`, only.

## The basic and boring way

```
data Tree a = Null | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

We start from a basic approach to define `treeFoldr`: we convert to list first, then use `foldr`.

```
-- In-order visit
toList :: Tree a -> [a]
toList Null = []
toList (Node l a r) = toList l ++ [a] ++ toList r

treeFoldr_1 :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFoldr_1 f x t = foldr f x $ toList t
```

## Equational reasoning to the rescue

Now we transform `treeFoldr_1` into a recursive definition, removing the intermediate list and the `foldr` call.

We split the definition of `treeFoldr_1`, by cases on `t`.

```
treeFoldr_2 :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFoldr_2 f x Null         = foldr f x $ toList Null
treeFoldr_2 f x (Node l a r) = foldr f x $ toList (Node l a r)
```

We expand `toList`.

```
treeFoldr_3 :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFoldr_3 f x Null         = foldr f x []
treeFoldr_3 f x (Node l a r) = foldr f x (toList l ++ [a] ++ toList r)
```

Here we exploit a `foldr` property:

```
--   foldr f x (ys ++ zs) = foldr f (foldr f x zs) ys
```

obtaining

```
treeFoldr_4 :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFoldr_4 _ x Null         = x
treeFoldr_4 f x (Node l a r) = 
    foldr f (foldr f x ([a] ++ toList r)) (toList l)
```

Again, we apply the same `foldr` equation.

```
treeFoldr_5 :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFoldr_5 _ x Null         = x
treeFoldr_5 f x (Node l a r) = 
    foldr f (foldr f (foldr f x (toList r)) [a]) (toList l)
```

By definition of `foldr`, we can simplify

```
--    foldr f z [a] = f a z
```

obtaining

```
treeFoldr_6 :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFoldr_6 _ x Null         = x
treeFoldr_6 f x (Node l a r) = 
    foldr f (f a (foldr f x (toList r))) (toList l)
              -- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, `foldr f x (toList t)` is `treeFoldr f x t`, so we can try
a recursive call to replace that pattern.

```
treeFoldr_7 :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFoldr_7 _ x Null         = x
treeFoldr_7 f x (Node l a r) = 
    foldr f (f a (treeFoldr_7 f x r)) (toList l)
 -- ^^^^^^^...........................^^^^^^^^^^
```

Again, same pattern.

```
treeFoldr_8 :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
treeFoldr_8 _ x Null         = x
treeFoldr_8 f x (Node l a r) = 
    treeFoldr_8 f (f a (treeFoldr_8 f x r)) l
```

... and we are done. No more lists around!

## Small test

```
test :: Tree Int
test = Node 
       (Node Null 2 Null) 
       5 
       (Node
        (Node Null 4 Null)
        1
        (Node Null 7 Null))

foo :: Int -> String -> String
foo n s = "(" ++ show n ++ ", " ++ s ++ ")"

--  *TreeFoldable> treeFoldr_8 foo "X" test 
--  "(2, (5, (4, (1, (7, X)))))"
```

Comment: The OP clearly was able to do `map`, so I was trying to help him (her?) get started on `fold` without writing out the code.

Comment: @ErikR Since they wanted a lot of functions, I thought it was ok to show how to craft one of those. IMO, the good answers must either provide some hints only (like yours -- perhaps with slightly more help), or explain the reasoning in detail. The really bad answers are those who hand out the code with no careful explanation. (And, by the record, I don't agree with who downvoted you)

Comment: great answer! :) the simpler the building blocks, the higher the building; the smaller the steps, the farther you go!  --- (just 2 add that it's an *in-order* traversal of the tree; another thing is, the flipped type `:: (a -> b -> b) -> Tree a -> b -> b` would lead to more visually apparent code, directly corresponding to the *difference-list* technique).

Comment: Indeed, as @WillNess suggests, there are multiple reasonable definitions of `foldr` for binary trees. Each corresponds to a different definition of `foldMap`, and I think it can be easier to understand them in the `foldMap` context, though the OP didn't mention that. That said, I greatly appreciate this answer. The demonstration of equational reasoning is great.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something which may help you:

Let `t1` be this tree (of type `Tree String`)

```
     "a"
     / \
   "b" "c"
   /     \
 "d"     "e"
         / \
       "f" "g"
```

First - how would you write it in terms of `Null` and `Node` constructors?

Second - what would `fold (++) t1` be?